# Jquery/Ajax/HTML assistance needed

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to build a very basic message center.  My idea is to use Jquery to make an ajax call to a classic asp page that will build a Json array.

I then plan to use Jquery to grab that Json.

My main questions currently are:

1. Is it possible to empty out a multi select input list?
2. Would it be better to not use the input at all and build a nifty Jquery list?
3. Will using Ajax allow me to on the fly empty this list; replace with with different information and/or append items to this list all without a page refresh?

I need to be able to allow the client to select multiple people from this list.  Is my outline above feasible?

Is it a good way to achieve what I am looking for?

I have very little experience with Json and Ajax, and was hoping someone could confirm if it was possible before I dive in.

Comment: 1: yes, 2: define 'better,' 3: yes. I'd strongly suggest that you attempt to build whatever this is, then come back to us with any problems that you're having. As it stands this question can't be answered with a single 'correct' answer, which I suspect falls under the remit of 'not constructive.' Please read the [faq].

Comment: By better I mean mostly ease of use with design coming in a close second.  I guess with CSS and your answer already it probably doesn't matter a whole lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it possible to empty out a multi select input list?

   **Yes**
2. Would it be better to not use the input at all and build a nifty Jquery list?

   **You can have this work with any kind of element, including a standard input.**
3. Will using Ajax allow me to on the fly empty this list; replace with with different information and/or append items to this list all without a page refresh?

   **Yes, in a function that handles the response of the Ajax call and uses call's result to populate the list. Since you're using Ajax, the call is asynchronous so the entire page will not be refreshed as a result of your call.**

Comment: Thanks, I think that answered what I was looking for perfectly.

Comment: Then you should mark it as the answer by clicking underneath the bottom arrow. :)

Comment: I can't for another 5 minutes.  But I will do so when able! :)